# Remove DIv with Specific ID from a DIV stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When admin changes the status of an order, markup of `#shipping_addr_detail_div` is sent to server to be sent via Email to customer.

There is a DIV `#dont_show_in_email` inside `#shipping_addr_detail_div`.

I am sending markup of `#shipping_addr_detail_div` at server side but I do not want `#dont_show_in_email` inside this.

Here is one of my attempt to do so

```
    var shipping_addr_detail_div = $("#shipping_addr_detail_div").html();

    shipping_addr_detail_div.find("#dont_show_in_email").remove();
```

this give me error `TypeError: order_items_detail.find is not a function`

I know I can remove it with `$("#shipping_addr_detail_div #dont_show_in_email").remove()` but it is also removed from my HTML page in browser.

**To be precise:**

Remove `#dont_show_in_email` from the markup stored in `shipping_addr_detail_div` variable but do not remove `#dont_show_in_email` from the page being displayed in browser

Comment: change `var shipping_addr_detail_div = $("#shipping_addr_detail_div").html();` to `var shipping_addr_detail_div = $("#shipping_addr_detail_div");`, because `.html()` returns a string, and strings don't have a `.remove()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the html of element without its child element:

```
$("#shipping_addr_detail_div").clone()
        .find('#dont_show_in_email')
        .remove()
        .end().html()
```

### Working Demo

**Here is how it works:**

-clone the element

-find and remove the element that is not required

-use `.end()` to end the most recent filtering operation in the current chain 
and return the set of matched elements to its previous state. i.e.`#shipping_addr_detail_div` in your case

-get the html of element

Comment: alert("Thanks al lot for the effort ... ");

Answer (score 0):

There is one important thing that you need to change in this exmaple.

Your exmaple: `$("#shipping_addr_detail_div").clone().find("#dont_show_in_email").remove();`

Right example:
var searchVar = $("#shipping_addr_detail_div").clone();
searchVar.find("#dont_show_in_email").remove();

In the first exmaple the problem is in remove. You'll see in your result "dont_show_in_email".
In the second example the result is element with id shipping_addr_detail_div without element "dont_show_in_email".

Or you can use the code of " Satpal".